# How to create a line of objetive in my visualization on PowerBi

Tags: powerbi, dax, powerbi-desktop

**I'm trying to visualize a chart with a line value for my Objetives** so i created a table with the values of my objetives for each of departments in my database.

[image: This is my database with my 3 main tables that i need for this exercise]

In my chart i want that it shows me the number of department by observer and observed and that values i have in my OPS table. That table is joined with the referencia_direcciones table where i have each of department i have and my objetivos table i have teh values of objetives for each department as i'm going to show you in the following tables:

[image: OPS Table]

[image: Referencia_direcciones Table]

[image: Objetivos Table]

This are my charts without tha Objetivos values

[image: Chart1]

And this is what returns me when i add the Objetivos values to the line values in my chart

[image: The line is counting me the number of values i have but not the values the table have]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is most likely due to you having [DepartPadreObservado] and [DepartObservadoNombre] from the 'OPS' table as the X-axis value and the [Objetivos] from the 'Objetivos' table as line value.

Based on your relationship image, there is a one-directional 1:* (one to many) relationship from 'Objetivos' to 'OPS'. This means that if you select one department from the 'Objetivos' table the corresponding department in the 'OPS' table will be filtered.

However, since it's one-directional, the filtering will not go the other way. I.e. when you select one department from the 'OPS' table, the model can not filter the 'Objetivos' table and thus you get the entire 'Objetivos' table. That's why the line is horizontal (same value for all [DepartPadreObservado] and [DepartObservadoNombre]).

One solution might be to change the one directionality of the relationship to bidirectional. This means that filtering works the same way in both directions, not just from 'Objetivos' to 'OPS'. N.B This is not best practice. You should look for a way to construct your model so that you only need one-directional relationships.

Example:

I have two tables, 'Fact' and 'Ref':

[image]

There's a 1:* relationship from Ref -> Fact:

[image]

If I now create the same type of diagram as you, with 'Fact'[Dep] as the X-axis value and sum of 'Ref'[Ref] as line value I end up with this:

[image]

However, by double-clicking on the relationship in the relationship view and changing it to bidirectional, I end up with this:

[image]

Be sure that by changing the directionality in the filtering, you don't screw up some other measure you've created.

Comment: Happy to help, hope you've gained some insights as well. Cheers